# Can I Use Tkinter window in Kivy as a sub-part of GUI?

Tags: python, tkinter, kivy

I am new to kivy and Tkinter.

**I want to use kivy as my root (main) GUI. But I also want to add Tkinker in it as a sub-part.**

**is it possible to integrate (fix) tkinter window in kivy  GUI  as sub part ???**

example :

kivy code :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.image import Image

class MyApp(App):
  def build(self):
    return Image(source="./Logo.png")

MyApp().run()
```

**kivy output :**

[image: kivy output]

Tkinter code :

```
import tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title("GUI")

tkinter.Label(window, text = "Username").grid(row = 0) 
tkinter.Entry(window).grid(row = 0, column = 1) 
tkinter.Label(window, text = "Password").grid(row = 1)
tkinter.Entry(window).grid(row = 1, column = 1) 
tkinter.Checkbutton(window, text = "Keep Me Logged In").grid(columnspan = 2)

window.mainloop()
```

**tkinter output :**

[image: thinter output]

**expected output :**

[image: expected output]

I tried to integrate both code, but it execute one after another.
any way to add tkinter window in kivy GUI.

Comment: I recommend you do not combine libraries that handle GUI since each one has an evenloop, so the kivy eventloop would block the tkinter eventloop, or vice versa. And the eventloop serves the GUI to get OS information, user events, etc. So the general answer is no. IMHO I think the form can be done with just kivy

Comment: It is possible to have a borderless tkinter window hover over the Kivy window in that spot but there'll will a lot of code to achieve that and also not recommended at all. Both GUIs can do what you want separately.

Comment: You should not expand the question as it would be too broad and could be closed. The best thing is to create a new question. Read [ask]

Comment: @eyllanesc ok, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to kivy window load tk. But you can try make as two programs with statick positions (but that is hardway), or just see how to write all code in one framework

Answer (score 1):

It probably is possible to run Kivy in an opengl context within a tkinter window, but there's no support for this and you'd have to write a fair amount of code to get it to work. Essentially you'd need to write a tkinter backend provider for the Kivy window.

I wouldn't recommend this, it would be much easier to do everything within one framework.